# AngularJS chart library

Tags: angularjs, charts

I'm actually searching for an AngularJS library which makes charts, I found some but none can make charts with handlers for clickable points.
I need a library where we can click on the chart points to "select them", but after hours of search I still couldn't find any.

Does a library like this exist or will I have to make one?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean drilled down chart?

Comment: No, line charts with points clickable or "selectable" , it's for a function who need two entry points and output the middle point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Highcharts library to accomplish the same,t o make the points on the chart clickable set allowPointSelect as true

```
plotOptions:{
  series:{
    allowPointSelect: true
  }
}
```

now you handle the click event or selection event from the

```
plotOptions:{
  series:{
    point:{
      events:{
        select: function(e){
          //your logic here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M5E5r/1/)**